# Use vbscript to test local user credentials

Tags: authentication, vbscript

I'm making a installer, using a vbscript to validate user account.

How could I test the password that user typed?
I've used the code below, but it doesn't work, return true on wrong password even.

```
Const ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = 1
Function CheckCredentials(Domain, Account, Password)

    Dim objIADS
    Set objIADS = GetObject("WinNT:").OpenDSObject("WinNT://" & Domain , Account, Password, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)

    If err.number = 0 then
    CheckCredentials = True
Else
    CheckCredentials = False
End If
End Function
```

What's wrong with the code ?
Thanks

Comment: If the Account parameter contains the same user as the owner of the vbscript process it may ignore the password and just reuse a previously existing directory connection. Just a guess. Is the password also ignored if you make sure that Account is not the currently logged of Windows user ?

Comment: Hi, @Morbo, I've tested with another user, and it still returns yes.

Comment: Hi, @Morbo, I've tested and found that even I use a account that doesn't existed at all, it still return yes. I use Set objNTInfo = CreateObject("WinNTSystemInfo")
ComputerName = UCase(objNTInfo.ComputerName) to get the domain. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the command doesn't generate an error when it fails. Try checking `If objIADS Is Nothing` to see if it failed instead.

Comment: @Morbo, I fixed this problem by changing the COM object to "GetObject("WinNT:").OpenDSObject("WinNT://" & Domain & "/" & Account & ",user" , Account..", use user interface solve the problem. Thanks